# Переставить столбцы в прямоугольной матрице

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

В заданной прямоугольной матрице с количеством строк n и столбцов 2n переставить столбцы в следующем порядке: 1, n+1, 2, n+2, 3, n+3, … n, 2n. Например, в матрице с шестью столбцами итоговый порядок столбцов должен быть следующим: 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6. Количество строк в матрице должно задаваться с клавиатуры.
Помогите написать алгоритм для перестановки столбцов. Вот фрагмент моей нерабочей задумки:

```
int k=1;
int m=2*n
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for (j = 1; j <= m; j++){
                if(j==k){
                    printf("%d",A[i][j]);k++;}
                else
                    if(j==n+k){
                        printf(" %d",A[i][n+k]);k++;}
                    else
                        break;}}
```

Comment: Не `if(j=k)`, а `if(j == k)`. То есть не присваивание, а сравнение. Сам код не проверял может в логике есть ошибка. Что за переменная `k`? `m`? `i`?

Comment: Это была опечатка. Через k хочу вывести первый столбец, m=2*n, i - счетчик из неотобразившейся строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать последовательно, то можно прийти к такому решению:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    //Ввод числа
    int n;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    //Заполнение исходной матрицы
    int m = 2*n;
    int matrix[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }

    //Вывод исходной матрицы
    printf("Matrix: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Транспонирование исходной матрицы для более простого обращения со столбцами
    int transMatrix[m][n];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            transMatrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Вывод транспонированной исходной матрицы
    printf("\n");
    printf("Transponirated matrix: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d", transMatrix[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Фильтрация (упорядочивание) столбцов исходной матрицы
    int transNewMatrix[m][n];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j += 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            transNewMatrix[j][i] = transMatrix[j/2][i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            transNewMatrix[j+1][i] = transMatrix[j/2+n][i];
        }
    }

    //Вывод новой транспонированной матрицы
    printf("\n");
    printf("Transponirated new matrix: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d", transNewMatrix[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Транспонирование новой матрицы
    int newMatrix[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            newMatrix[i][j] = transNewMatrix[j][i];
        }
    }

    //Вывод новой матрицы
    printf("\n");
    printf("New matrix: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d", newMatrix[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Пропустив промежуточный вывод, получим:

```
Matrix: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 3 4 5 6 7 

New matrix: 
0 3 1 4 2 5 
1 4 2 5 3 6 
2 5 3 6 4 7
```

Comment: До такого я еще не додумывалась

Comment: Не легко раз уж вы создаете новую матрицу сразу её и заполнить нужным образом?

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример намного проще с созданием всего одной побочной матрицы и 1 циклом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int m = n << 1;

    int t = 0;
    int A[n][m];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            A[i][j] = ++t;
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    int B[n][n << 1];
    int k = 0, l = n;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int* tmp = &k;
        if(i % 2 == 1) tmp = &l;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            B[j][i] = A[j][*tmp];
            
        (*tmp)++;
    }
    
    printf("Новая матрица: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", B[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```